# PromiseKit 2.0: chaining promises doesn't pass argument

Tags: ios, swift, promisekit

I have wrapped 2 of my API requests with Promise<T> return types:

```
func registerWithEmail(email: String, firstName: String, lastName: String, password: String, subscribe: Bool) -> Promise<Bool>

func requestAccessTokenWithEmail(username: String, password: String) -> Promise<String>
```

Using them individually works fine:

```
firstly {
    client.registerWithEmail("foo@gmail.com", firstName: "john", lastName: "smith", password: "password", subscribe: false)
    }.then { success -> Void in
        completion(success: success)
    }.catch { error -> Void in
        println(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

And:

```
firstly {
    client.requestAccessTokenWithEmail("foo@gmail.com", password: "password")
    }.then { accessToken -> Void in
        println(accessToken)
        completion(success: true)
    }.catch { error -> Void in
        println(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

However, when I chain them, the token argument to the second `then` call is never populated:

```
firstly {
    client.registerWithEmail(username, firstName: "a", lastName: "b", password: password, subscribe: false).then { success -> Void in
        return client.requestAccessTokenWithEmail(username, password: password)
    }.then { accessToken -> Void in
        println(accessToken)
        completion(success: true)
    }
}
```

If I break inside this closure I can't view the `accessToken` argument, only the outer `completion` closure. However, if I break inside the `requestAccessTokenWithEmail` function, the `accessToken` argument is populated when calling `fulfill`.

I'm quite new to PromiseKit, so please let me know if I'm doing something stupid.

I'm using PromiseKit 2.0, Swift 1.2, Xcode 6.4

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the signature of the first `then` closure.

It was `success -> Void` but needed to be `success -> Promise<String>`

I thought that would've been caught by Swift's type inference but I forgot that `then` is overloaded to accept closures of both `(T) -> Promise<U>` and `(T) -> U`.

Hopefully when Swift fixes the need for the explicit signature in the `then` closure it will be automatically inferred.